# Using fractional base when summing taylor series causes infinite loop?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that will approximate e^x using taylor series as follows:
 [image: taylor-series for exp(x)]

I created a function that will do the summation, taking in n (number of times to sum) and x (the exponent) and another function that takes in a number and returns its factorial. Pretty simple stuff I think. The problem I'm having is when I input a fractional x first (for instance, .5, 6) the program just hangs. If I first input something like (3, 6) and then after that calculation, I input (.5, 6)I will get an infinite loop. If the x I input is not a fraction, I can do the calculation as many times as I like.

I feel that it must have something to do with my call to the pow() function. I think I'm using it correctly (pow(double, int)) but does it not take fractions or something? I don't understand.

Here's my code:

```
double taylorSeries (double x, int n, double &error)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i <= n; i++)
        sum += (pow (x, i))/(factorial (i));
    error = (fabs(exp(x) - sum));   
    return sum;
}

long factorial(int n) 
{ 
    long factorial=0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        if (i == 0)
            factorial = 1;
        else
            factorial = factorial * i;
    }
    return factorial;
}
```

And then the call to the taylorSeries function in main looks like this:

```
cout << "please enter x and n: ";
cin >> x >> n;
cout << "taylor series sum = " ;
cout <<  taylorSeries (x, n, error) << endl;
//cout << "error = " << error;
```

Can someone help me figure out why this isn't working?

Comment: I don't suggest using the same name "factorial" as the number.

Comment: Is `x` defined as `double` in `main`? I'm guessing it's `int`.

Comment: Verify your x and n before calling the function. Print them. Check your stream read them properly.

Comment: `factorial` is over-complicated but correct. Though shadowing names in outer scopes is error-prone.

Comment: By the way on a technicality this is not a Taylor Series which is a way to evaluate f(x+d) from f(x) and derivatives. It is similar in the sense that it is an infinite series with factorial coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind some of the inefficiencies of your algorithm, the most likely cause for your function seemingly fail to return is a bad parsing of `x` and thus `n` not getting set at all, which means it could hold any random value.

Your line:

```
cin >> x >> n;
```

If it fails to parse into `x` properly then it will not attempt to parse the next number because the input stream will be in an error state.

If `n` has not been initialised it could hold any value which might in reality be an extremely big integer. Thus your algorithm appears not to ever return.

```
int main()
{
   double x = 0.0;
   int n = 0;
   double error = 0;
   cout << "please enter x and n: ";
   cin >> x >> n;
   if( cin )
   {
         cout << "taylor series sum, x=" << x << " n=" << n << " : ";
        cout <<  taylorSeries (x, n, error) << endl;
        cout << "error = " << error;
   }
   else
   {
       cerr << "invalid input" << endl;
   } 
}
```

For a more efficient algorithm:

```
double taylorSeries (double x, int n, double &error)
{
    double sum = 1;
    double xpow = x; // would start at 1 but we have implemented exponent of 0
    double fact = 1;

    for (int i=1; i <= n; i++)
    {
       fact *= i;
       sum += xpow / fact;
       xpow *= x;
    }

    error = fabs(exp(x) - sum);   
    return sum;
 }
```

Your `factorial` function is technically correct until the point where it will overflow.

Comment: So when you say "bad parsing," what exactly do you mean? Sorry I'm just not sure. 

So you've initialized x, n, and error to zero, makes sense. What is the purpose of the if (cin) statement? Under what conditions will cin return true/false?

Comment: if the user did not enter a valid floating point number or integer.

Comment: Aside from the condescending nature of your reply, I appreciate the help. Thanks. If I had enough rep I would vote you up.